# Solving the problem of a curve with no stationary points

Tags: derivatives

The curve $y=2x^3+ax^2+bx-30$ has no stationary points.

Show that $a^2<6b$.

How can I solve this?

Comment: How would you find stationary points if there were any?  What does having no stationary points then imply?

Comment: It means the derivative of the function is not equal to zero.

Comment: And it means the derivative of the function is either positive or negative.

Comment: What is the derivative of the function?  What happens when you solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ for $x$?  Or try to complete the square?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's look at the derivative:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=6x^2 + 2ax + b$$

Since there are no stationary points, then $\not \exists x$ where $6x^2+2ax+b=0$. When does that happen? The function $f(x)=6x^2 + 2ax + b$ does not intersect the $x$-axis if and only if there are no roots to $f(x)=0$. This happens when the discriminant $D$ of the quadratic is $D<0$. The discriminant is given by

$$D = 4a^2 - 4\cdot 6 \cdot b < 0$$

Which implies $a^2 < 6b$.